# How do I allow clients to upload to Amazon S3 without giving out my keys?

Tags: session, amazon-s3, key

One of my clients has a site which displays media that has been uploaded from a client application.

This application initially used FTP, but we're moving to S3 for various data storage and performance reasons.

What I would like to be able to do is have this client upload a file directly to our central S3 store (ala dropbox/jungledisk etc etc), but I can't see a way of doing this without handing over our keys and embedding them in the application - not ideal!

Is there any way to furnish a client application with a session key / temporary upload URL / something? This could be done via our website's api - which of course has full access to any required S3 secret keys.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this should be possible.  What you need to do is create a signed policy file *per-upload* or *per-user*.  That policy file, the signature, and some other data must be sent by the client program using a POST request to the bucket you'd like them to use. Amazon will examine the request, check that the parameters are within the limits of the policy file that accompanies the request, and then allow the post.  Note that this *policy* should not be confused with the *bucket policy*. This is, in fact, a policy which could change per request if you wanted, and it is submitted by the client program (after the client program obtained a signed copy from you).

Full details on this can be found in the [Browser Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingHTTPPOST.html) section of the S3 documentation. I'd recommend a detailed review of the [HTML Forms](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html) section, and a review of how to get the POST parameters to your client (for a browser you can send it HTML, which is how the documentation is worded, for a non-browser program you probably need an API call of some sort followed by the client submitting a POST to S3).

You can also check out this web page which can give you an idea about how to setup the parameters: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-example-code/post/post_sample.html

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to do it using form based HTML upload: This [article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/) does a good job explaining how it is possible. After reading the [article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/) you can use my scripts mentioned below to make life easier.

Here is a python script I use for generating my policy, its signature and base64 string.

> IMP: Make sure the policy.json file is in the same directory

```
import base64
import hmac, hashlib
import os
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'Your Access Key'

os.system('clear')
print "This policy generator is for key : " + AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY  
print "Make sure this is the correct key."
print "IMP: Please be consistent with the file policy.json small changes in space or newline can fail policy"

policy_document = file("policy.json",'rb').read()
policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())

print
print "Policy (BASE64_POLICY to be inserted in HTML):-"
print policy
print
print "Signature:-"
print signature
print
```

And here is the corresponding policy.json file I use:

```
{
  "expiration": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.00Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "BUCKET NAME" },
    ["starts-with", "$key", "PREFIX_IF_ANY"],
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://REDIRECTED_URL" },
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "CONTENT_TYPE"],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576],
  ]
}
```

The HTML form for this code is as such:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>S3 POST Form</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>

    <body> 
        <form action="http://BUCKET_NAME.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="key" value="picbum/${filename}">
            <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AccessID"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://REDIRECTED_URL">
            <!-- Fill these HTML fields with data generated from python script -->
            <input type="hidden" name="policy" value='BASE64_POLICY'>
            <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="SIGNATURE_GENERATED">
            <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="CONTENT_TYPE">
            <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

            File to upload to S3: 
            <input name="file" type="file"> 
            <br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is my vote because of the article that explains everyting.